# What do Cuban power plugs look like?

Tags: cuba, power

What do Cuban power plugs look like? Are they like US or UK ones?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Cuba uses type A and B 110V, 60Hz power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country).  So you can expect to see the following two types:

[image: Type A plugs]
[image: Type B plugs]

This is the same as the United States.  UK plugs will not work without a method of converting.

Comment: Great answer!. By the way, the 110V thing is just theoretical, I never got more than 100V in my former appartment :)

Comment: @yms 110V is just nominal anyway, there will always be *some* line losses, anywhere in the world. That's why electricity meters measure both voltage and current, and  multiply them together to find the power you are consuming. What surprises me is that you made  regular practice of measuring the voltage.

Comment: @steveverrill power outages were extremelly common in Cuba during the 90-ies and early 2000s (up to 16 hours par day during the worst period), and when the power came back, the voltage was sometimes as low as 70-80V. I am not an expert on the field, but I used to wait for a while until it was a bit higher to turn on some of the electrical appliances at home. At some point the government started to sell a "protection device" that did more or less the same thing.